# NGiNX and MediaWiki rewrite regular expression

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex, mediawiki, regular-expressions

I am having some problems with regular-expression with rewrite in NGiNX.

Here is my config:

```
location /wiki/ {
            rewrite ^/([^?]*)/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /$1/index.php?title=$2&$3 last;
    }
```

Here is the URL of the main page: //example.com/wiki/en/Main_Page

I have two problems.

First when I go to this URL: //example.com/wiki/en

It says the page does not exists. Is there a way to force a / to be added a the end of the "en" at the end of the URL? Because if you go to //example.com/wiki/en/ with the / at the end

Second problem:

The images are not loading.

Here is the URL of the position of MediaWiki images: //example.com/wiki/en/skins/common/images/*image name*

So is there a way for my regular expression to ignore the URL if it is trying to get an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /wiki/ {
    rewrite ^/wiki/en$ /wiki/en/;
    rewrite ^/([^?]*)/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /$1/index.php?title=$2&$3 last;
}
location /wiki/en/skins/common/images/ {
}
```

Comment: en is the language used. How do you make it so that I can have multiple languages? Thanks.

Comment: By the way your config works. I just forgot to specify that "en" could be another value. Not more than two.

Comment: If in place of "en" there could be any two lower case letters, then use the following instead: `rewrite  ^/wiki/[a-z][a-z]$  $uri/;`.